# LIMIT in PHP mssql_query?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using PHP to connect to a MS Sql database.
I've got it all working except I can't seem to get the LIMIT to work.

The following query returns an error:

```
$query = "SELECT name, id, startDate FROM events LIMIT 0, 20";
```

Here's the Error it's returning:

> Warning: mssql_query()
>   [function.mssql-query]: message:
>   Incorrect syntax near '0'. (severity
>   15) in
>   /var/www/vhosts/[hidden]/index.php on
>   line 201

I've also tried using the following:

```
$query = "SELECT name, id, startDate FROM events LIMIT 20";
```

But it returns the same result.

Now, the same query without the "limit" in it, returns fine... but loads over 6,000 results which I obviously don't want :)

Anyone have any ideas?
Troy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LIMIT is MySQL syntax -- on SQL Server, you need to use [TOP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP 20 
       e.name, 
       e.id, 
       e.startDate 
  FROM EVENTS e
```

Unlike LIMIT, TOP doesn't have the ability to specify an offset in case you're looking to use this for pagination.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using MySQL syntax on a SQL Server.  SQL Server doesn't have the LIMIT option.  You can try the TOP command in SQL Server.